# Correlation function from Laplace transform of distribution function?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, stochastic-processes

I have a time-dependent random process $x(t)$ which takes on two values $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$. I know the Laplace transforms of the (time-dependent) probabilities $\hat{p}_{ij}(s)$ of these values ($i,j=1,2$), representing the probability that the system is in state $i$ at $t$ given it was in $j$ at $t=0$.

$$ \hat{p}_{ij}(s) = \int_0^\infty dt e^{-st}p_{ij}(t),$$

but I can't perform the inverse Laplace transform to obtain the time-dependent probabilities. I'd like to calculate the two-time correlation function:

$$C(t_1,t_2) = \langle x(t_1) x(t_2) \rangle = \sum_{i,j = 1,2} \Delta_i \Delta_j p_{ik}(t_1)p_{jk}(t_2).$$
From this point I have two questions.

First, is this expression for the correlation $C(t_1,t_2)$ technically correct? As this process is in general non-stationary I expect the correlation function to be dependent on the initial deterministic state $k$, however I'm somewhat uncertain if $p_{ik}(t_1)p_{jk}(t_2)$ is the proper two-time probability distribution required to calculate the correlation function.

Second, is there a possibility of getting at $C(t_1,t_2)$ from $\hat{p}_{ij}(s)$? Is double-Laplace transforming the correlation function expression to obtain $\hat{C}(s_1,s_2)$ a valid procedure?

Comment: What do you mean "resists [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform)"?

Comment: I mean someone could get a closed form for the inversion perhaps if their last name was Abrikosov, Prudnikov, or maybe Landau. I don't see it happening for kevinkayaks. Is there a way to proceed in transform space?

Comment: lol, i see. Other thing: can you define in the question $C(t_1,t_2)$ in terms of $P(x,t)$ so we are all on the same page?

Comment: The question is quite abstract. While it might be possible to solve the problem as stated, it would probably be beneficial (as in, you'd be more likely to get an answer) to tell more about the concrete problem you're trying to solve. I take it autocorrelation of a given process? Do you care if it's done via transforms or not? Also, why do you know the Laplace transform in space? Normally I'd expect Laplace in time, Fourier in space.

Comment: Thanks you two. I reworked the question a lot.